# minimum value of $3$ square root function of variables $x,y$

Tags: inequality, optimization, triangles, radicals, geometric-inequalities

Finding minimum value of $$\sqrt{x^2+49-7\sqrt{2}x}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2-\sqrt{2}xy}+\sqrt{y^2+25-5\sqrt{2}y}, x,y \in \mathbb{R}$$

Attempt: $$\sqrt{(x+7)^2-14x-7\sqrt{2}x}+\sqrt{(x+y)^2-2xy-\sqrt{2}xy}+\sqrt{(y+5)^2-10y-5\sqrt{2}y}$$

could some help me how to solve it , thanks

Comment: Is the answer $12$ (approximately)

Comment: @ArchisWelankar $\approx 11.11$ IMHO.

Comment: Oh yes missed some number in middle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can assume that  $x$ and $y$ are non-negatives.

Consider three triangles $\Delta ABC$, $\Delta CBD$ and $\Delta DBE$,

where $\measuredangle ABC=\measuredangle CBD=\measuredangle DBC=45^{\circ}$, $AB=5$, $BE=7$, $CB=y$ and $DB=x$.

Thus, $AC+CD+DE\geq AE=\sqrt{25+35\sqrt2+49}=\sqrt{74+35\sqrt2}.$

The equality occurs, when $\{C,D\}\subset AE$, which is possible of course.

Comment: @Durgesh Tiwari What do you think about my solution? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain how did you calculate AE .I mean $\angle ABE \neq 45degrees$

Comment: @navinstudent $\measuredangle ABE=135^{\circ}$ and from $\Delta ABE$ we have $AE=\sqrt{5^2+7^2-2\cdot5\cdot7\cdot135^{\circ}}=\sqrt{74+35\sqrt2}$