# Minimum value of an expression in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, radicals, geometric-inequalities

$$\sqrt{x^2-7\sqrt{2}x+49} + \sqrt{x^2+y^2-\sqrt{2}xy} + \sqrt{50+y^2-10y}$$

$x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, what is the minimum value?

I have tried finding the minimum value of the first expression and the third expression, with the first expression being $\frac{7}{\sqrt{2}}$ while the second expression being $5$, I do not know how to move on from this (note that the answer is an integer from $0$ to $999$).

Comment: I just included some mathjax to improve the visuals of your question. You can find a quick tutorial about how to write formulas with mathjax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It is very easy.

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2234862/minimum-value-of-3-square-root-function-of-variables-x-y), so perhaps any method to solve one solves the other.

Answer (score 2):

Let $OABCD$ be a pentagon such that $OA=5\sqrt2$, $OB=y$, $OC=x$, $OD=7$, $\measuredangle AOB=45^{\circ}$, $\measuredangle BOC=45^{\circ}$ and  $\measuredangle COD=45^{\circ}$.

Thus, $$\sqrt{x^2-7\sqrt{2}x+49} + \sqrt{x^2+y^2-\sqrt{2}xy} + \sqrt{50+y^2-10y}=$$
$$=DC+CB+BA\geq AD=\sqrt{(5\sqrt2)^2+7^2-2\cdot5\sqrt2\cdot7\cos135^{\circ}}=13.$$
The equality occurs, when $\{B,C\}\subset AD,$ which says that $13$ is a minimal value.

Done!

Comment: How did you even get this idea of pentagon!

Comment: @samjoe We see the possibility to use the law of cosines and by this thing we got a pentagon. It's something like this.

Answer (score 0):

let $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2-7\sqrt{2}x+49}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2-\sqrt{2}xy}+\sqrt{50+y^2-10y}$$
then solve
$$f_x=1/2\,{\frac {2\,x-7\,\sqrt {2}}{\sqrt {{x}^{2}-7\,\sqrt {2}x+49}}}+1/2
\,{\frac {2\,x-\sqrt {2}y}{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-\sqrt {2}xy}}}
=0$$
and
$$f_y=1/2\,{\frac {2\,y-\sqrt {2}x}{\sqrt {{x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-\sqrt {2}xy}}}+1/
2\,{\frac {2\,y-10}{\sqrt {{y}^{2}-10\,y+50}}}
=0$$